# Formatting just one line vb6 word 2007 bar code

Tags: vb6, ms-word, automation, format

I am automating a word document with a single table, using vb6.  I have the following:

```
strCellContents = "s " & CStr(oRec("sphBase")) & "     c " & CStr(oRec("cylAdd")) & vbCrLf
strCellContents = strCellContents & oRec("Description") & vbCrLf
strCellContents = strCellContents & "1010" & CStr(oRec("RightOPC")) & vbCrLf
strCellContents = strCellContents & "1010" & CStr(oRec("RightOPC")) & vbCrLf
oDoc.Tables(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 6
oDoc.Tables(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
oDoc.Tables(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = InchesToPoints(0.11)
oDoc.Tables(1).Cell(row, col).Range.Text = strCellContents
If Not oRec.EOF Then
    oRec.MoveNext
End If
```

You will note I repeat one of the lines twice, giving me four lines of text in each of 30 cells (3 cols 10 rows).  I want the first instance of the repeated line to have a bar code font.  How would I go about formatting just that line?  I have the bar code font and it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer 
    iNumWords = oDoc.Tables(1).Range.Words.Count 
    ''modify font of bar code (3rd line) - underline for now 
    For q = 1 To iNumWords 
        If CStr(oDoc.Tables(1).Range.Words(q)) = strSKU Then
            oDoc.Tables(1).Range.Words(q).Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle 
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next